# How can I order users by the number of questions they have asked on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, users

How can I order users by the number of questions they have asked on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Use SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1004641/users-with-the-most-questions) will do the trick:

[image]

Please note that the SEDE database is updated once a week, on Sunday morning. Though for this query, that should not lead to problems. Feel free to [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/1004641) the query and play with it; take the [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) @rene linked to if you want to know more about SEDE.